# wxPython application does not exit from systray icon left-click

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

when I left-click my icon in the system tray it does not exit the application - I can see it does go through the function though when I set a breakpoint, if however I click Exit from the popup menu then the program exits as expected (runs the same function), why is this please?

It is the on-exit function that should close the application:

**self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_exit)**

Thanks very much for any help you can provide.

```
import wx
import wx.adv

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'ShutMeDown'
TRAY_ICON = icon.png

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.Append(item)
    return item


class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.SetIcon(wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(TRAY_ICON)), TRAY_TOOLTIP)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_exit)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True


def main():
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try changing `on_exit` to:
        self.frame.Close()
        self.Destroy()

Comment: Thanks very much @RolfofSaxony that worked.  Do you know why it did not work with the original code please?

Comment: Definitively? No. But it makes sense to close in a logical order and to be explicit rather than implicit. At a guess, using `wx.CallLater(100, self.Destroy)` would probably have worked as well. `wx.CallAfter` might not be what you think it is. It calls the specified function after the current and pending event handlers have been completed. Which may be `now` to `whenever`.